# How do I use php to link to a page with variables in the url?

Tags: php, get

So let's say the current url is...

```
.../friends.php?episode=1&season=1
```

How would I be able to have a default '*next*' button to go to the next episode.

I know how to retrieve the variable with

`$_GET[episode]` and `$_GET[season]` and save it to a variable.

Then I can add one to one of them with restrictions...  (and subtract)

But I can't figure out how to make it a link that I can press to go to next or previous.

Comment: You can for your easily by getting values from url and adding and subtracting 1 from variables, check my code below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `http_build_query` function:

```
$season = $_GET["season"];
$episode = $_GET["episode"];
$query = http_build_query(array("season" => $season, "episode" => $episode+1));
```

EDIT: I've switched the episode and season increment, now it increments the episodes.

Then concat this with the link:

```
echo "<a href='/page.php?$query'>Next Episode</a>";
```

Comment: Oh nice, I never heard of this function! The documentation is here if you need it : http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: double quotes - they tend to parse variables inside them, so that they are a bit slower that single ones. This should be, like, `$_GET['season']` and `$_GET['episode']`

Comment: True, but in this case, the slowdown caused by the extra parsing is so small, it is practically negliglibe :)

Answer (score 1):

**Working Code**

```
<?php
$season = $_GET['season'];
$episode = $_GET['episode'];

echo '<a href="friends.php?episode='.($episode - 1).'&season='.$season.'"> Back Episode  </a>-----';
echo '<a href="friends.php?episode='.($episode + 1).'&season='.$season.'">  Forward Episode  </a><br>';

echo '<a href="friends.php?episode='.$episode.'&season='.($season-1).'"> Back Season</a>-------';
echo '<a href="friends.php?episode='.$episode.'&season='.($season+1).'">Forward Season</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

just construct the link you want and then put it into an `a` HTML element:

```
$link = "./friends.php?episode=" . $_GET['episode'] . "&season=" . $_GET['season'];
echo "<a href='$link'>Next episode</a>";
```